# How to use Icontains to search in ListField as the source is an array?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am using Django to query data in my MongoDB. I have this document in my DB:

```
{
"source": "www.google.com",
"hierarchies": [],
"mainTags": [
    "Sobre a página",
    "Teste Tag",
    "Cartão de Crédito"
],
"email": "a@a.com",
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ba7ffee2ef3f4139de74f3d"
},
"updated_at": {
    "$date": 1537725886501
},
"created_at": {
    "$date": 1537725886501
},
"title": "Relação de seguros entre 2017 e 2016",
"tableId": "relacao_de_seguros_entre_2017_e_2016_7836c6e2",
"relevance": 1.0,
"description": "este dataset tem como função mostrar a Relação de seguros entre 2017 e 2016",
"tags": []
```

}

And my entry should be something like: `["Sobre", "Teste"]`

I'm trying to find all documents where my **Maintag** contains any of my **entry** values. This is what I did:

```
    for word in keywordsArray:
        q |= Q(mainTags__icontains = word)
    objects = Metadata.objects.all().filter(q).order_by('relevance')
```

I also tried :

```
    objects = Metadata.objects.all().filter(Q(mainTags__in=mongoKeywords)).order_by('relevance')
```

But when I pass `["Sobre", "Teste"]` as entry, it didn't find nothing. how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, and your question is..?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

well i am not aware of django but this works in normal mongoshell query. It will find all document where tag is Sobre or Teste. /i signifies ignore case search

```
db.collectionName.find({
"mainTags": {"$regex":/^Sobre$|^Teste$/i}
})
```

Other option is :

```
db.collectionName.find({
    "mainTags": {"$in":["Sobre","Teste"]}
})
```